# Moodle File API : multiple rows?

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

In a Moodle form I perform a file upload using the `filemanager` element:

```
$mform->addElement('filemanager', 'attachment',get_string('displayedcontent', 'block_helloworld'), null, $filemanageropts);
```

Once the form is validated, when I record my instance in the database, I also save the uploaded file using the following function:

```
file_save_draft_area_files($form_submitted_data->attachment, $context->id, 'block_helloworld', 'attachment',
    $form_submitted_data->attachment, array('subdirs' => 0, 'maxbytes' => 500000, 'maxfiles' => 1));
```

This is working fine but when I take a look at the DB table `mdl_files`, I saw that for my file there are 4 rows:

```
component       fileare     itemid  filepath    filename
block_helloworld    attachment  706783489   /   .
block_helloworld    attachment  706783489   /   test5.pdf
user    draft   706783489   /   .
user    draft   706783489   /   test5.pdf
```

There are 2 rows for my uploaded file in my component `block_helloworld` and in the component `user`.
One row has a filename but not the other one!

This sounds strange. Is that normal? 
When I perform file deletion, how to delete all these files?

*Note: I am using moodle v3.0.6*

Comment: Which Moodle version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, this is normal behaviour. I had this issue, too, but when you cross check (like doing a file upload into a course) you will notice that there are 2 rows, too. Not sure, why but for me it was normal behaviour

Answer (score 1):

The 4 entries are:

- The folder that your file is in
- The file itself
- The folder that the draft version of the file is stored in whilst the form is being edited
- The draft file whilst the form is being edited

The draft files will be automatically cleaned up after a day or so.

Comment: ok, when I am implementing the delete page, I only have to remove the 2 rows for my component `block_helloworld` (and do not care about the `user` component rows) ?

Comment: If it's in the block context and you're deleting the block, then Moodle should clean up automatically. If not, just use the files API to delete the area - you should never need to access mdl_files directly.

Comment: for sure I will only perform file deletion using the built in file API but when I perform the deletion, I only have the row with the filename that is deleted. The row where filename='.' is still in the mdl_files. Is that normal ? Should I add code using file API to remove this line too ?

Comment: Are you just deleting a single file, or are you calling $fs->delete_area_files(...) to remove the entire area?

Comment: I am deleting a single file retrieved from : `$fs->get_area_files(...)` which returns an array of size 1. Thus, the row where filename='.' is still in the `mdl_files` table. Shall I try `$fs->delete_area_files(...)` limited by $itemid ?